# Calculate percentage along with groupBy in Grafana

Tags: jmx, grafana, graphite, codahale-metrics, grafana-api

I am logging a success count metric and failure count metric for every 30 seconds into graphite. In the Grafana, I am using per second and hitCount(1minute) that aggregates the count(success and failure) for every minute.  Now I need to calculate the percentage of success for every minute? Any advice on how to proceed?

Also, I am using groupbyNode on the fourth metric * mentioned below.

```
Success metric : api.server.metric.*.success.count
Failure metric : api.server.metric.*.failure.count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
asPercent(api.server.metric.*.success.count,sumSeries(api.server.metric.*success.count, api.server.metric.*.failure.count),0)
```

or if you just have failure and success as values :

```
asPercent(api.server.metric.*.success.count,api.server.metric.*.*.count,0)
```